# my OS is windows7，i want to build the developing environment of sakai oae

Tags: maven, ojdbc

my OS is windows7，i want to Deployment the environment of sakai oae

```
When I run
    mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.oracle-jdbc-6 -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=10.2.0.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=org.sakaiproject.nakamura.ojdbc.jar -Durl=url -DrepositoryId=repositoryId

I got the error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:
deploy-file (default-cli) on project org.sakaiproject.nakamura.ojdbc6: No transf
er protocol found. -> [Help 1]
```

i don't know Why.

Comment: try adding a debug parameter `mvn -X` to see the actual problem...

Comment: Can you post the full command line (i.e. including the url and repository ID you used). Also, can you post the part of your `settings.xml` file that defines the repository.

Comment: my OS is windows7，i want to Deployment the environment of sakai oae

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install the oracle jdbc jar to your local repo. Don't do this from within the OAE source that contains a POM as it will try to read the POM and it gets confused. Just do it from a new directory and it should be installed in your local repo.

Have a look at the bottom of this page for more info about running the mvn deploy plugin to install jars into your local repo:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html