# i want to build the developing environment of sakai oae on windows 7,but i don't know how to do it?

Tags: sakai, ojdbc

my OS is windows7.in the cmd, i run:

```
  cd sakai3/3akai-ux
  mvn clean install
```

i got:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

then i run:

```
cd sakai3/nakamura
set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=256m"
mvn clean install
```

i got this error:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.sling:maven-launchpad-plugin:2.1.0:pre
    pare-package (prepare-package-jar) on project org.sakaiproject.nakamura.app: Una
    ble to find artifact. Failure to find org.sakaiproject.nakamura:org.sakaiproject
    .nakamura.ojdbc:jar:CURRENT-VERSION in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached
     in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update in
    terval of maven repo has elapsed or updates are forced
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
    [ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.sakaiproject.nakamura -DartifactI
    d=org.sakaiproject.nakamura.ojdbc -Dversion=CURRENT-VERSION -Dpackaging=jar -Dfi
    le=/path/to/file
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file t
    here:
    [ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.sakaiproject.nakamura -DartifactId=
    org.sakaiproject.nakamura.ojdbc -Dversion=CURRENT-VERSION -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile
    =/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] org.sakaiproject.nakamura:org.sakaiproject.nakamura.ojdbc:jar:CURRENT-VE
    RSION
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
    [ERROR] maven repo (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, releases=true, snapshots=fal
    se),
    [ERROR] apache-snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/, releases=fals
    e, snapshots=true),
    [ERROR] sakai-releases (http://source.sakaiproject.org/maven2/, releases=true, s
    napshots=false),
    [ERROR] sakai-snapshots (http://source.sakaiproject.org/maven2-snapshots, releas
    es=false, snapshots=true),
    [ERROR] java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2, releases=true, snapshots=fal
    se),
    [ERROR] modularity-releases (http://m2.modularity.net.au/releases, releases=true
    , snapshots=false),
    [ERROR] modularity-snapshots (http://m2.modularity.net.au/snapshots, releases=fa
    lse, snapshots=true),
    [ERROR] OPS4J (http://repository.ops4j.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=fals
    e),
    [ERROR] sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/, relea
    ses=true, snapshots=false),
    [ERROR] sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/
    snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true),
    [ERROR] central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=f
    alse)
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
    ch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
    d the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
    xception
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.sakaiproject.nakamura.app
```

then i install the org.sakaiproject.nakamura.ojdbc.jar use this command under the folder D:\sakai3\nakamura\contrib\oracle-jdbc:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.sakaiproject.nakamura -DartifactId=org.sakaiproject.nakamura.ojdbc -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -Durl=url -DrepositoryId=repositoryId
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.sakaiproject.nakamura -DartifactI
        d=com.oracle-jdbc -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfi
        le=ojdbc6.jar
```

then i got a new error：

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:
deploy-file (default-cli) on project org.sakaiproject.nakamura.ojdbc: No transfe
r protocol found. -> [Help 1]
```

what should i do next???i have searched many website,but i haven't got a good idea.i don't know where i wrong or what i missing?
I an a chinese.please forgive my broken English.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to ask on the [Sakai OAE developers list](http://collab.sakaiproject.org/mailman/listinfo/oae-dev).

But I believe the problem is the same as [what I answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116929/my-os-is-windows7i-want-to-build-the-developing-environment-of-sakai-oae).